# Show a column of Join in CakePHP3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm working in CakePHP3, and I readed the official book but not found this. I want to show a column of other table, using join. I have this code:

```
 $id = $this->Auth->User('idUsuarios');
 $lastquery = TableRegistry::get('Apuestas');
 $query = $lastquery->find()
         ->join([
        'Juego' => [
            'table' => 'juego',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Apuestas.juego_idJuego = Juego.idJuego'
        ]])
->where(['usuarios_idUsuarios' => $id])
->order(['fecha' => 'ASC'])
->limit(1);

 $this->set(compact('query'));
```

But it don't shows any table of the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this part of book.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Choose the most appropriate association

Let my show yo my example:

- Country **HasMany** Comunites
- Comunity **HasMany** Spots, **BelongsTo** Country, **HasMany** Provinces
- Province **HasMany** Spots, **BelongsTo** Cominities
- Spot **BelongsTo** Countries,
  **BelongsTo** Comunites, **BelongsTo** Provinces

Later, to show specific spot by $id

```
$spot = $this -> Spots -> find()->where(['Spots.id' => $id])-> contain(['Provinces' => ['Communities' => ['Countries']]])->first();
```

Now I can call in view e.g. `$spot -> province -> name` or `$spot -> country -> name`